# Power Query - Is there anyway to not refresh a table connect to a mapping?

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a mapping **“Dpt_floor”** that together with another file **“Dpt_resp”** is used to create a quarterly template. The template is created by merging those two mappings.

The data in the mapping tables can change from a quarter to another.
My goal is to not update the template used in the previous quarters once the data in the mapping **“Dpt_floor”** changed. So, to not refresh at all the data coming from **“Dpt_floor”** in the template but just the one coming from **“Dpt_resp”**.

I have tried to turn off the options Enable background refresh and Refresh this connection on Refresh all in Properties for the connection to **“Dpt_Floor”** but if you right click on the template and hit refresh everything will get refreshed anyway.

I am not the only user of the file so I cannot assume that nobody will right click and refresh the template.

Is there any way to achieve that goal?

Comment: Might help, can you go through it : **[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/150408/power-query-in-excel-disable-query-from-refreshing)** --> the second answer seems a good workaround.

Comment: It can be a good workaround!

Comment: When you have resolved it successfully, make sure to post the same as an answer so it helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Within the Excel (not Power query editor) UI, you can edit a query's properties turn off refreshing when refresh all is clicked.

But if that doesn't work, a way I've done this is:

- write `Dpt_floor` to a worksheet,
- import that new table into a new `Dpt_floor Prev` query
- duplicate your `Dpt_floor` query and call it `Dpt_floor Next`
- Change your original `Dpt_floor` query to

```ml
let
  Source = fPrevOrNext("Dpt_floor", #"Logical value that's true if Next should be used"),
  #"Changed Column Types" = ...
...
```

and then make a query called fPrevOrNext with code of

```js
// if you don't use a convoluted function like this that goes through #shared then, as optimized as power query is, there's still overhead against *both* queries even if you'll only use one!
(QueryName as text, UseNext as logical) =>
let
  Suffix = if UseNext = true then " Next" else " Prev",
  n = QueryName & Suffix,
  ret = Record.Field(#shared, n)
in
  ret
```

This lets you programmatically control if `Dpt_floor` is refreshed. For example, it could be false unless Dpt_floor hasn't already been refreshed this quarter.

This is especially useful when you have a lot of queries like that, or if your set of queries are so complex and take such a long time and you want a "cheat mode" to enable during development.